# Freeradius: MySQL query to show account expired yesterday

Tags: mysql, radius

I have freeradius with mysql.using CLI, I want to list user account which have expired yesterday. 
Currently I am using following command but it shows today account,

`mysql -uroot -pSQLPASS -e "use radius; select login,expirydate,mobile from users where expirydate = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY);"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql -u$SQLUSER -p$SQLPASS -e "use $DB; select login,expirydate,mobile from users where expirydate = CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;"`

This is showing accounts which expiry date is yesterday. I hope it's correct way.